# What is the residue of $f(z) = z\sin(z + {1 \over z})$ at $z_0 = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I want to determine the residue of $f(z) = z\sin(z + {1 \over z})$ at $z_0 = 0$. I think that this an essential singularity and I want to work with the Laurent series which should be given by:

$$z \sin\left(z + {1 \over z}\right) = z \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^n \over (2n + 1)!} \left(z + {1 \over z}\right)^{2n+1}.$$

I don't know how to continue

Comment: The residue at $z=0$ is the coefficient of $\frac1z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $f(z)$ is an even function of $z$.

Comment: This is definitely how to continue.